# How to set input field with current date in angular

Tags: html, angular

I want my form date input field to display today's date e.g (2019-11-28) when I open the form. I saw many examples on how it works in AngularJs but how can I get the date with reactive form.

**form**

```
//.....
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Date:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control col-md-8" formControlName="date"/>
      </div>
</div>
.
//...
```

With formControlName.

**.ts**

```
//...
currentD = new Date();

..
..
//....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `formControlName` default value as `(new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10)`

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-wm9qwm?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Try like this:

.ts

`myForm:FormGroup;`

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({    
 'presentDate': new FormControl((new Date()).toISOString().substring(0,10))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use data bindind you can use one way binding

```html
<input type="date" [value]="currentD" class="form-control col-md-8" formControlName="date"/>
```

or tuo way binding

```html
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="currentD" class="form-control col-md-8" formControlName="date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a **`FormGroup`** variable to assign the value to Form

```
 form : FormGroup;

 // you can set the default value
constructor( fb:FormBuilder){
   this.form = fb.group({
      presentDate: [new Date()]
   });     
}
```

In the View

```
<div class="form-group">
 <form [formGroup] = "form">
  <label>Date:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control col-md-8" formControlName="presentDate"/>
      </div>
</div>
```